# How to pass variables from JSON to postman body

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to parameterized my tests in Postman. This is the example body of POST request:

```
{
  "entity_id": "{{entity_id}}",
  "text": data.comment_name
}
```

`entity_id` is global variable and it works correctly, but I want to set value of `text` from JSON file.
`data.comment_name` doesn't work it saved me exactly `data.comment_name` as text variable. I want to include this JSON file with all variables in collection runner. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried this without adding the “data” part and using  just `{{comment_name}}`

Comment: that's work, thank you :)

Comment: Awesome! I've added an answer to the question. If it's correct and works for you, please close out this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your data file looks something like this JSON example:

```
[
    {
        "entity_id": 1,
        "comment_name": "This is my comment_name"
    }
]
```

To reference the values in the file, the POST body needs to look like this:

[image: Postman Body]

This is how your example would be but you don't need to add the `" "` around the variable. This could cause issues if the value is a number and adding the quotes around the value in the request body, would make this a string and possibly lead to a bad request.

Answer (score -1):

##### Pre-request Script <sup>[Add variable to JSON body](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/request/9215231-c85a1e86-f643-4648-b125-ebea1c5d782b)</sup>

By using `pre-request scripts` we can change the variable values, parameters, headers, and body data before a request runs by execting JavaScript.

> Post URL : `http://postman-echo.com/post`  <sup>Code tested in [Postman-win64-8.12.4-Setup](https://quickstarts.postman.com/)</sup>

> Request Body - raw

[image]

```json
{
    "locale": "en_US",
    "key"   : "{{dynamic_key}}",
    "value" : "{{dynamic_val}}"
}
```

> `Writing pre-request scripts`

[image]

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("dynamic_key", "key1");
pm.collectionVariables.set("dynamic_val", "val1");

console.log('Add variable to JSON body', pm.request.body);
```

---

- [Sending parameters](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#sending-parameters) [*Query parameters*(`?id=1&type=new`), *Path parameters* (`/customer/:id`)]
  [image]